# Polymer core-menu double event

Tags: javascript, browser-history, polymer

I'm using [Polymer](http://www.polymer-project.org) for my web-app and I'm currently having some issues with page linking. It's the first site I'm making using all ajax/javascript, thus I haven't used the history functions of javascript a lot yet.

Anyhow, I have a main menu in the left sidebar. When one of those is pressed, it should change the url of the browser and also put it in the history of the browser. To do so I have the following code:

```
Polymer('my-app', {
    mainMenu: function(){
        this.$.mainPages.selected = this.$.mainMenu.selected;
        console.log("Pusing state " + this.$.mainMenu.selected);
        history.pushState(null , "title", this.$.mainMenu.selected);
    }
});
```

Now the problem is that it gets called twice, so if you click once the pushState is called twice. Needless to say this is not good.

I have made a sample code here: [click me](http://jsbin.com/luwitudu/1/edit).

In this sample code you can see after pressing a couple of menu-items, first of all the event gets fired two times. I've also noticed when pressing the back-button, updating the page seems to also refire the `pushState`.

So in short, my **first concern** is that the event of pressing an element from the [`core-menu`](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-menu), the `mainMenu` function is called twice. **Second concern** is that I am repushing states when going back, which I presume should be prevented as well.

**Updated code:**

```
Polymer('my-app', {
    ready: function(){
        var link = document.URL.split("/");
        this.$.mainMenu.selected = link[link.length-1];
        console.log("ready with link: "+link[link.length-1]);
        window.onpopstate = function(){
            var link = document.URL.split("/");
            console.log("Calling onpopstate. New link is: "+link[link.length-1]);
            this.$.mainMenu.selected = link[link.length-1];
            this.$.mainPages.selected = this.$.mainMenu.selected;
        }
    },
    nav: function(){
        this.$.drawerPanel.togglePanel();
    },
    back: function(){
        window.history.back();
    },
    mainMenu: function(){
        console.log("Pusing state " + this.$.mainMenu.selected);
        this.$.mainPages.selected = this.$.mainMenu.selected;
        history.pushState(null , "title", this.$.mainMenu.selected);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are much better off using data-binding. The idea here is to make your element model-driven, an model-view-presenter (MVP) pattern. The model is made up of properties in your element, the view is described by the template, and the presenter is in your script. Data-binding allows us to loosely couple the view from the logic.

Let's decide the current page will be controlled by a property called `page`.

Then we can set up our UI to be driven by the `page` property:

```
  <core-menu selected="{{page}}" valueattr="id">
     ...
  </core-menu>
  <core-animated-pages class="main" selected="{{page}}" valueattr="id" transitions="slide-from-right">
```

This is good because we have decoupled the UI from the code. The code never talks directly to the `core-animated-pages` or the `core-menu` (notice I removed the `id`s). We don't listen to any events. This way we can change the UI at will without having to modify the script.

Now, we want the `page` to be initially selected by the URL, so we'll initialize it that way, or default to 'home'. We also want to synchronize `page` to back events, so we'll listen to `onpopstate'.

```
   ready: function() {
      // scrape the initial page off the window location
      this.page = location.hash.slice(1) || 'home';
      // listen for 'back' events
      addEventListener('popstate', this.popstate.bind(this));
   },
   popstate: function(event) {
     // comes here whether we went 'back' from code or UI
     this.poppedPage = this.page = event.state;
   }
```

We keep track of `poppedPage` so we can differentiate back and forward. We only want to push a new state when we go forward.

Now we need the page to be reflected in the history, so we need to push state when the page changes. As above, the one caveat is that we need to only push the state if we are going forward.

```
    pageChanged: function() {
      // if the selected page changes, push a state (unless we are going backward)
      if (this.poppedPage !== this.page) {
        history.pushState(this.page, "Title", '#' + this.page);
      }
    }
```

Here it is all put together:

http://jsbin.com/luwitudu/9/edit

Comment: I must say, this is a very neat solution. Also a fan of the `location.has.splice(1)`, but my site goes up to three levels deep and I'm not quite sure if that's able to be done clearly with hashtags. Also wasn't aware of the [`changed watchers`](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#change-watchers), will come in handy in the future as well!

Comment: And on a sidenote - any idea if it is possible to get eg the `label`-attribute of the selected page? It would be better to display the label in the heading and page title than the id (eg `Home` instead of `home`). Currently I just display `{{page}}`, so the id is printed.

Comment: <h1>{{pageItem.label}}</h1>
      <core-menu selected="{{page}}" selectedItem="{{pageItem}}" valueattr="id">

Answer (score 2):

You get two events, one for the deselection of the currently selected item and one for the new selected item. Check the event object that is passed to your callback function:

```
mainMenu: function(e) {
  console.log(e.detail.isSelected);
  console.log(e.detail.item);
}
```

But if you use `on-core-activate` your callback is only called once when a menu item is tapped by the user (it is not called when you change the menu selection programmatically.) This prevents the unwanted window history push when you change the menu selection in your program.

Then you should setup a `window.onpopstate` callback in which you select the (previous) menu item. If you call `document.URL` in you `back()` function, it will return the current URL, not the new one set by `window.history.back()`. Instead only pop from the history in this function.

This should work:

```
<core-menu ... on-core-activate="{{mainMenu}}">

Polymer("my-app", {
  ready: function() {
    var self = this;
    this.$.mainMenu.selected = "home";
    history.pushState(null, "Title", this.$.mainMenu.selected);
    window.onpopstate = function() {
      var link = document.URL.split("/");
      self.$.mainMenu.selected = link[link.length-1];
      self.$.mainPages.selected = self.$.mainMenu.selected;
    };
  },
  mainMenu: function() {
    this.$.mainPages.selected = this.$.mainMenu.selected;
    history.pushState(null, "Title", this.$.mainMenu.selected);
  },
  back: function() {
    window.history.back();
  }
});
```

Comment: Note that `core-activate` fires every time an item is clicked, even if already selected.